# Anytime I use a command it says "command not found" or doesn't say anything at all

Tags: python, discord.py

I created a bot but it isn't working properly so I restarted it and even the most simple command doesn't work - any reasons why?

I keep getting an error

> commandnotfound. command 'hi' is not found

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot (command_prefix = "*")


@bot.event
async def on_connect():
 print ("it worked")

@bot.command
async def hi(ctx):
  await ctx.send ("hello")

token=("....")
bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct decorator for a command is `@bot.command()`
Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
  await ctx.send("hello")
```

And you have used:

```py
@bot.command
async def hi(ctx):
  await ctx.send ("hello")
```

The problem was that you didn't call the decorator, which must be followed by `()`.
You did well with the `@bot.event`, which doesn't need to be called.